# How to extract property from JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, object

I am using a library called mxGraph and in my code I subscribe for an event. In the callback function I receive according to the documentation the sender object and the event object. I outputted the event object to the console and got the following:

[image]

My question is how to get `cells`?

Thanks.

Martin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mxEventObject.properties.cells
```

or

```
mxEventObject['properties']['cells']
```

Comment: according to the output, properties is an array, so you would need a [] or similar in there somewhere.

Comment: no, this works fine.  in javascript lines blur in the differences between an `Array` and an `Object`.

Comment: Yes, it works fine. I was trying with `mxEventObject.properties[0].cells` but getting `mxEventObject.properties[0] is undefined`

Comment: yes, generally speaking array's in javascript are simply objects with enumerated property names.